# How to regenerate image thumb with size that is specified in media section

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have 500x300 sized images in my all post and want 280x177 sized images to display in index page for all the post. I used regenerate thumbnails and AJAX thumbnail rebuild plugin which builds images using setting in media section but problem is that after building some of the images it stops reacting and just hangs. Why this is happening? Is these plugins not work with more images. I have approximately 2000 images. Please help me. How to rebuild this images. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely, your issue is the large number of images, causing the processing to time out.

Try increasing your PHP script execution time, and see if either Plugin can complete.

Alternatively, I believe that one or both of those Plugins allows for manual thumbnail regeneration, via `Dashboard -> Media`.